# Using Django Gargoyle how do I create my own condition set?

Tags: python, django, gargoyle

I'm using Django's sites framework and would like to use [Gargoyle](https://github.com/disqus/gargoyle/) to enable/disable functionality on a site-by-site basis. This would involve creating my own condition set for `Site`.

I've read the [Condition Set API reference](http://readthedocs.org/docs/gargoyle/en/latest/ref/conditions.html) and had a look at the built in sets which come with Gargoyle, but I'm still at a loss as to how I should go about creating my own sets.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Gargoyle yet (though it's on my list of things I'd like to play with), and I agree - the [documentation for ConditionSet](http://readthedocs.org/docs/gargoyle/en/latest/ref/conditions.html) doesn't look too helpful. Maybe looking at the source for [`builtins.py`](https://github.com/disqus/gargoyle/blob/master/gargoyle/builtins.py), which has the built-in ConditionSets, might help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very difficult to create a new condition set, you can have a look at what I have done here for example

(I needed a switch based on Django settings' X == value Y):

https://github.com/WoLpH/gargoyle/commit/85b9cc13ca44e1396521ceba0ea3eb25bf5b0506